# How to solve the problems in "sudo apt-get update"

Tags: apt, repository

[Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13029929/sources.list) is my `/etc/apt/source.list` file. I get many problems in the output of `sudo apt-get update`:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for tim: 
Err http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu precise/ Release.gpg                          
  Could not connect to cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu:80 (169.229.201.201). - connect (111: Connection refused)
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main Sources        
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net precise/main i386 Packages  
  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu/precise/Release.gpg  Could not connect to cran.cnr.Berkeley.edu:80 (169.229.201.201). - connect (111: Connection refused)

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/venerix/blug/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/venerix/blug/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I have several errors at the end of the output.
How can I solve the problems?

Thanks!

Comment: For clarification, I have many errors in the output at the end. I edit post for that.

Comment: [Here is one more link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey), this will help you with NO_PUBKEY

Comment: [One more link](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=127293), will help you with `404  Not Found`

Comment: If it is still a problem I can summarize all in answer. Just let me know. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I updated the output, and the remaining is what I still don't know how to solve.

Comment: Exactly which is the problem right now?

Comment: Search for "Err" and "fail" in the output, @Braiam

Comment: Please edit your output and narrow it down. Each "Err" depending the reason are solved differently